# Issuer vs Entity Id

Tags: connected-apps, saml

I can't get a clear answer on what the difference is between Issuer vs Entity Id. I think it depends on the context of if Salesforce is a Service Provider (SP) or Identity Provider (IdP).

**Salesforce as a SP**

> Issuer: unique url of the IdP

> Entity ID: unique URL that identifies your identity provider as the recipient of SAML requests that Salesforce sends. This entity ID must be the same as the `<saml:Issuer>` attribute in the SAML assertion.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_saml.htm&type=5

**Salesforce as a IdP**

> Issuer: salesforce my domain url

> Entity Id: the globally unique ID of the service provider.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=connected_app_create_saml_sso.htm&type=5

---

I think this is correct, but I'm confused what the Entity Id is when Salesforce is a SP. It looks like the exact same thing as the Issuer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Entity ID: unique URL that identifies your identity provider as the
> recipient of SAML requests that Salesforce sends. This entity ID must
> be the same as the `<saml:Issuer>` attribute in the SAML assertion.

The above definition is quite confusing in the "Salesforce as a Service Provider" scenario and I had tried to make sense out of this sentence many times in the past. IMO, its factually incorrect and Salesforce should either correct it or provide clarification on what they actually mean. In the realm of SSO implementation (outside SF), entity ID & Issuer are sometimes used interchangeably. However, when it comes to SF SSO, in all the implementations I've tried and all the related SF videos that I've seen, the simple definition is as follows:

> Issuer: Unique URL of Identity Provider

> Entity ID: Unique URL of the Service Provider